# pagination with chromeless in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pagination

I am using the [chromeless](https://github.com/graphcool/chromeless/issues/261) headless browser on AWS Lambda.

I'm trying to figure out how to paginate content, but I'm new to node and async/await.

This is my code:

```
const Chromeless = require('chromeless').default

async function run() {
  const chromeless = new Chromeless({})

  var results = [];

  const instance = await chromeless
    .goto('https://www.privacyshield.gov/list')

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
  { 
    console.log('in for');
    instance
    .html()
    .click('a.btn-navigate:contains("Next Results")')
    .wait(3000)
    results.push(html)
  }

  await chromeless.end()
}

run().catch(console.error.bind(console))
```

but I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined
```

which means instance is not defined outside of await.  I don't wait to create separate instances in each for loop iteration, as I would lose my position on the page.

Answer (score 1):

It took some time to figure it out but was interesting, this is my first await async code from node too.

```
const { Chromeless } = require('chromeless')

async function run() {
  const chromeless = new Chromeless()
  let curpos = chromeless
    chromeless.goto('https://www.privacyshield.gov/list')
    .press(13)
    .wait(3000); 
  const page1 = await curpos.html()

  curpos = curpos.click('a.btn-navigate')
    .wait(3000);
  const page2 = await curpos.html()

  curpos = curpos.click('a.btn-navigate')
    .wait(3000);
  const page3 = await curpos.html()

  console.log(page1) 
  console.log("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
  console.log(page2)
  console.log("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
  console.log(page3)

  await chromeless.end()
}

run().catch(console.error.bind(console))
```

I hope you can take it to the loop from there.

Interestingly I was able to convert into ES5 code and debug it out.

Hope it helps.